# How to automatically append a certain phrase to all google search queries? Purpose: block certain domains

Tags: google-search

Basically Google doesn't have a "site exclusion" list AFAIK. Therefore the same crap sites keep polluting the search results again and again. What I would like is a way to automatically add "-site:x.com -site:y.com -site:z.c

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Basically, you change the search url for google which is by default

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=%s.
```

to

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=-site:z.c%20%s.
```

I can't test at the moment, so some adjustment might be needed.

When using the adress bar in order to search on google, it will automatically append `-site:z.c`